# How are eigenfunctions found?

Tags: operator-theory

Let's stick to the derivative operator and any other operators built up from it.  For instance, if $D = \frac{d}{dt}$, then the eigenfunction of $D$ is known to be $e^{at}$, associated with eigenvalue $a$.  However, what about for a more complicated operator?  Even something as simple as $1 + D$.

Is there a general method that works for any such operator?  For that matter, how was the eigenfunction for $D$ itself found?

Comment: In general, for an operation $T$, eigenfunctions are found by solving the functional equation $T(f) = f$.

Comment: Well...yes. I may not have been clear.  I think the question I had was: is there a general way to solve such an equation?

Comment: @DHMO $T(f) = \color{blue}{\lambda} f$...?

Comment: There are very many different methods to try and solve such equations.

Comment: $T(f) =\lambda f$ rather, for arbitrary $\lambda$. Then while solving the equation you get some additional conditions on $\lambda$, and then you would want to show that these are sufficient conditions for there to exist eigenvectors.

Comment: In this case, $D(f) = af$ is solvable through the integral $\int D(f)/f = at$, and eigenfunctions for your operator $1+D$  can be found in the same way

Comment: @mathreadler: I see, I guess much like differential equations.  I wonder, then, is there a suitable subset of operator equations that have a general method of solution, like the linear ODEs have?

Comment: As long as we can represent the operator in question and the identity operator in some vector space we can try and solve it using linear algebra.

Comment: Notice that linear ODEs /do/ comprise a class of operator equations, namely the class of equations of the form $P(D) f = g$, where $P$ is a polynomial with coefficients in an appropriate function space.

Comment: @mathreadler: I'd love to see an example of that, if you're willing (or can link it in).  I keep hearing that there is such a connection to vector spaces, but I've never been sure of how to set up the problem appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a minimal example an eigenfunction to the operator ${\bf T = D}^2+2{\bf D}$ on the space of $\{\sin(x),\cos(x)\}$.

The operator $D$ on this space is a matrix: $ {\bf D} = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$

Therefore $${\bf T} = {{\bf D}^2+2{\bf D}} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}-1&2\\-2&-1\end{array}\right]$$

We can now solve $\det({\bf T}-\lambda {\bf I})$

$\lambda = -1\pm 2i$ $e = [\pm \sqrt{1/2} i , \sqrt{2}]^T$

So if we allow complex coefficients, apparently second derivative plus 2 times derivative of $$\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} +2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right) \{i\sin(x)+\cos(x)\} = (-1+2i)(i\sin(x)+\cos(x))$$

And we can [check it on Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((d%5E2%2Fdx%5E2)(i*sin(x)%2Bcos(x))%20%2B%20(d%2Fdx)%202*(i*sin(x)%2Bcos(x)))%2F(-1%2B2i)).

Comment: Fascinating.  So we require a vector space of functions to be defined as well.  That's what @DHMO was getting at, right, except they used an infinite dimensional space?  Very interesting.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Eigenfunction of $D$

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
Df &=& af \\
\dfrac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dt} &=& af \\
\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm df} &=& \dfrac1{af} \\
t &=& \displaystyle \int \dfrac1{af} \ \mathrm df \\
t &=& \dfrac1a\ln f + C \\
f &=& ke^{at}
\end{array}$$

---

### Eigenfunction of $1+D$

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
1+Df &=& af \\
Df &=& af-1 \\
\dfrac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dt} &=& af-1 \\
\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm df} &=& \dfrac1{af-1} \\
t &=& \displaystyle \int \dfrac1{af-1} \ \mathrm df \\
t &=& \dfrac1a\ln (af-1) + C \\
at-b &=& \ln(af-1) \\
f &=& \dfrac{1+e^{at-b}}a \\
\end{array}$$

---

### In general

Apart from directly solving the equation, there are some general approaches.

For **certain** problems, one can use matrix to find eigenfunctions.

First, we choose a basis. A common basis is $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,\cdots\}$ (the polynomials). Then, we use a matrix to represent the operator, and then find the eigenvalue and the eigenvector of the matrix. The eigenvector represents the eigenfunction.

**Limitations**: Only works when the operator is **linear**, and obviously the basis cannot represent all functions.